# Realm do not migrate

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I am using Realm (v2.7.0) in my iOS-app. After the first release, I changed some Models that I want to migrate.

To do this migration, I've added this code to the `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion == 0) {
                // Changes for scheme v0 to v1
                print("Doing migration.")
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Category.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    newObject!["id"] = String(describing: oldObject!["id"])
                }

                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Income.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    newObject!["id"] = String(describing: oldObject!["id"])
                }

                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Expense.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    newObject!["id"] = String(describing: oldObject!["id"])
                }

                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Debt.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    newObject!["id"] = String(describing: oldObject!["id"])
                }
            }
    })

    // Execute Migration
    let realm = try! Realm()

    return true
}
```

The problem is that this codeblock never execute. I still get the errors:

```
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors
```

When I put some breakpoints in my `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` they will never reached. So it looks like that the method will not called before the error appears.

What to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using iOS storyboards perchance? Storyboard instantiation occurs before the Application delegate has a chance to call, so it's possible your code is executing a `let realm = Realm()` statement before the migration block is properly set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the initialize lazy then the controller will wait until migration is done. if you do not make it, it will try to initialize before migration is done. The problem occur there.

```
lazy var realm:Realm = {
    return try! Realm()
}()
```